# Is there no way to adjust billing_cycle_anchor on Stripe's subscription_update_confirm deep link flow?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

Our service awards monthly credits, and therefore handles upgrades and downgrades differently - upgrades get processed straight away so users have access to their new credits. Billing cycle gets changed to 'now' and proration is 'none'. Downgrades do not prorate either, but billing cycle stays the same as it was and the changes to don't apply until next cycle.

I realize this is not normal behavior and so the normal billing portal won't work for ugprade/downgrade. However, developers told me to check out the subscription_update_confirm flow for portal sessions (https://stripe.com/docs/customer-management/portal-deep-links).

I dove into this and had to setup a portal configuration for each type of upgrade, but then found out you can't seem to adjust billing_cycle_anchor with a portal configuration either.

I know I can use webhook to change a subscription before it goes into effect, but the whole point is that I want a consistent Stripe-hosted confirmation page when a user does their upgrading or downgrading. Is there any other way I'm not considering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior is expected here.

Stripe's [Billing Customer Portal](https://stripe.com/docs/customer-management/integrate-customer-portal#configure) doesn't support updating the billing cycle anchor, so you would need to handle that particular flow outside of the Billing Customer Portal. The [deep link flow](https://stripe.com/docs/customer-management/portal-deep-links) doesn't add the ability to update billing cycle anchor either, unfortunately.